# Resize Buttons and Image in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been trying to get the ImageView and the 3 Buttons all in the same size (fitting the parent TableLayout) but for me it's turning out to be impossible and I was hoping someone could help me fix this problem in the .xml file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfDIK.png

This is the TableLayout I'm trying to put together and this is the code inside of it:

```
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iFoto"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/i_background" />
                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:stretchColumns="*" >
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/button1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@anim/btblue"
                            style="@style/ButtonText"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/button2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@anim/btblue"
                            style="@style/ButtonText"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/button3"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@anim/btblue"
                            style="@style/ButtonText"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
```

This is what I was hoping to get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaVd5.png

Can someone help me with this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this..

Change your Imageview Width&height attributes to like this..

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iFoto"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/bgd7" />
```